# mysql sum case error on text value

Tags: mysql

I have a little issue here. There are three tables:

Table 1

```
category_id        parent_id
     1                 0
     2                 1
     3                 0
     4                 0
     5                 10
```

Table 2

```
category_id         Name
     1              Cars
     2              Toys
     3              Gifts
     4              For women
     5              For men
```

Table 3

```
product_id       category_id
    1                 2
    1                 1
    2                 3
    2                 1
    3                 2
    4                 3
    4                 5
```

The numbers in product_id column can be repeated several times. **I want to join the tables and get each product_id with one row like this:**

```
product_id       category1      category2
    1              Toys           Cars
    2              Gifts          Cars
    3              Toys           Null
    4              Gifts          For men
```

The **parent_id** column has the numbers which specifies the type and level of the category, either is the main or sub category. This is my code but I get 0 in the

```
    SELECT product_to_category.product_id, sum(CASE(category.parent_id) WHEN 1 
    THEN category_description.name ELSE 0 END) as category1,
    sum(CASE(category.parent_id) WHEN 2
    THEN category_description.name ELSE 0 END) as category2
from category LEFT JOIN category_description ON 
category_description.category_id = category.category_id 
LEFT JOIN product_to_category ON category.category_id = product_to_category.category_id
group by category.category_id
```

when I execute it I get 0 values on category_main column

```
product_id          category1        category2
    1                   0                0
    2                   0                0
    3                   0                0
    4                   0                0
```

Comment: I have edited my question and provided the desired result set. Just don't know where I am wrong in the query

Answer (score 1):

change and check

```
SELECT tab.product_id, 
       Sum(category_id1) AS Category_id1, 
       Sum(category_id2) AS Category_id2 
INTO   #temptable 
FROM  (SELECT a.product_id, 
          0 AS Category_id1, 
          Min(a.category_id) AS Category_id2 
   FROM   #table3 a 
          INNER JOIN (SELECT product_id, 
                             Count(category_id) AS Category_id 
                      FROM   #table3 
                      GROUP  BY product_id 
                      HAVING Count(category_id) > 1) b 
                  ON a.product_id = b.product_id 
   GROUP  BY a.product_id 
   UNION ALL 
   SELECT a.product_id, 
          Max(a.category_id) AS Category_id1, 
          0                  AS Category_id2 
   FROM   #table3 a 
          INNER JOIN (SELECT product_id, 
                             Count(category_id) AS Category_id 
                      FROM   #table3 
                      GROUP  BY product_id 
                      HAVING Count(category_id) > 1) b 
                  ON a.product_id = b.product_id 
   GROUP  BY a.product_id 
   UNION ALL 
   SELECT a.product_id, 
          a.category_id AS Category_id1, 
          0             AS Category_id2 
   FROM   #table3 a 
          INNER JOIN (SELECT product_id, 
                             Count(category_id) AS Category_id 
                      FROM   #table3 
                      GROUP  BY product_id 
                      HAVING Count(category_id) <= 1) b 
                  ON a.product_id = b.product_id) tab 
GROUP  BY tab.product_id 

SELECT #temptable.product_id, 
       CAT1.name AS Category_id1, 
       CAT2.name AS Category_id2 
FROM   #temptable 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN #table2 CAT1 
                    ON #temptable.category_id1 = CAT1.category_id 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN #table2 CAT2 
                ON #temptable.category_id2 = CAT2.category_id
```

Comment: this way it works, it puts in 1s in the columns, but i want text values to be there instead. I have edited my question and provied the desired result set

Comment: so you do not need to apply any aggregate function.check my answer

Comment: No no, I guess you are not getting my point. I decided to edit the post. Please check my question again. I wasn't clear enough the other time

Comment: Oh ok so please take look at the my answer which you want.

Comment: It throws an error syntax to use near 'pivot ( max(value) for category_id in (cat1, cat2, cat3) ) piv' at line 7

Comment: you have some mistake to execute the query because answer query did not have 'pivot ( max(value) for category_id in (cat1, cat2, cat3) ) ' line.

Answer (score 1):

Why doesn't use a COUNT() and a WHERE? You wanna count how many category.parent_id are equals to 1, right? So:

```
SELECT category.category_id, COUNT(category_description.name)
category_main  FROM category 
LEFT JOIN category_description 
    ON category_description.category_id = category.category_id 
WHERE category.parent_id = 1 
GROUP BY category.category_id;
```

Comment: Beto, no no, you didn't get me. I want to have category_main to have the categories from another table where they equal to 1. I will edit my post and you will see it

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
category.category_id, 
category_main = CASE
                   WHEN category.parent_id = 1  
                   THEN category_description.name 
                   ELSE '0' 
                END
FROM category 
LEFT JOIN category_description ON 
category_description.category_id = category.category_id
```

Comment: it says category_main is unknown column. This is because it is not a real column but I want it to display in the result set. The category_description.name has text in its table

Answer (score 0):

Do you need each category in diferent columns?

If you dont need, use group_concat

http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/aggregate-functions-and-grouping/aggregate-functions-and-grouping-group_concat.php

Will be like that:

```
SELECT t3.product_id, GROUP_CONCAT(t2.name) FROM table3 t3
LEFT JOIN table2 t2 on t2.category_id = t3.category_id
LEFT JOIN table1 t1 on t1.parent_id = t2.category_id
GROUP BY t3.product_id
```

Comment: I exactly need the categories to be in different columns as I gave in example.